# carto db torque slider change color, font

Tags: carto, timeslider, torque

for a theatre project im trying to make a visualization about protests in the last decade. I managed somehow to do that but unfortunately the  default time-slider of carted is really small and not easy to notice when we are using a screening.

Do you know how to change the color/size maybe the font of the time-slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the slider you have two options:

- create a custom one based on the default: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/src/geo/ui/time_slider.js
- change current one styles with CSS, you just need to add a CSS file after loading cartodb.css